# What's this game shown on the Apple iPad page/website

Tags: game-identification

if anyone knows what this game is it would be a great help!

It looks like a great game to play

Thank you in advance ☺️

[image]

Answer (score 7):

By cropping and rotating the image to look like this:

[image: cropped image]

I was able to find the game, which is called **Vikings: an Archer's Journey**.

- [App Store link](https://appsto.re/us/EQRreb.i)
- [Google Play Store link](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.pinpinteam.vikings&hl=en)

Comment: Oh well it showed up as I was posting for some reason whoops

Answer (score 7):

It took *a lot* of searching for various things but *eventually* I found it!

The game is called: **[Viking: An Archer's Journey](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/vikings-an-archers-journey/id1145485982?mt=8)**

[Official Trailer.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AmXBs1z0M7g)

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to search! That's so kind of you!